# How do i allocate an array of bytes starting at address 0 in the LLVM IR?

Tags: linux, llvm, llvm-ir

I am trying to write an llvm instrumentation pass that creates a shadow table low in memory (from 0x10000 in Linux since this is the minimum value) and I am curious what is the canonical way of getting this done. I looked at both the DataFlowSanitizer and MemorySanitizer code but I am having some difficulties understanding how the system reserves this space for special use and makes sure it does not get trampled by alloca.

Comment: Actually I might have been a bit unclear. I am trying to write an instrumentation pass in llvm and trying to construct a shadow table starting somewhere low in memory. My understanding now is that mapping onto 0x0 is not possible in the current generation of Linux systems and the lowest value is 0x10000(my guess this is to prevent errors resulting from null pointers being dereferenced from inside the kernel). I looked at some sanitation passes but I am still not entirely sure how it works.

Comment: Updated the question to clarify some.

Comment: That's quite a change. The changed question is simpler though: If `mmap(0x10000, …, MAP_ANONYMOUS, …)` returns 0x10000, that memory is yours and yours alone. alloca uses the stack, which reserves its memory using the same call.

Comment: Or you can make the linker call mmap() for you by a suitable linker script. That way you have a compile-time guarantee. The program won't start unless the linker can mmap() all of the sections.

Comment: Thanks. Will the mmap calls interact at all with malloc?

Comment: malloc() returns memory it has obtained from the kernel, and it usually obtains memory by calling mmap(), so memory you malloc() and memory you mmap() definitely never overlap. (malloc() can also call sbrk(), but I'd be surprised if modern malloc() implementations do that, and anyways sbrk() calls the same kernel machinery as mmap() in the end.)

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: Actually I have one further thought since the mmap region would have to be allocated before the global data would this actually work for arbitrary programs on which the pass is operating on?

Comment: `if(mmap(0x10000, …) != 0x10000) exit(1)`. Or use a linker script to place a custom section at 0x10000, then the memory will be mmaped in as part of loading the program, ie. you have a link-time guarantee.

Comment: The reason i ask this question is it seems that certain passes in the system according to the comment do this automatically without resorting to a linker script. I.e. dataflow sanitizer. I am curious what procedure is being used to get this effect. It does seem that all pointer loads and stores off the heap are "relocated" by using a mask but i don't see a similar mask for alloca. I am wondering if this is done using the DataLayout or address spaces or something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, then the way to do that is called a [linker script](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Using_ld_the_GNU_Linker/simple-example.html).

A linker script directs the linker where and how to locate data in the output. "Place the read-only data at 0x70000, the read-write global variables at 0x9000 and the code at 0x42420000", that kind of thing. You can write a linker script to place global variables at 0x0, make a GlobalVariable that's an array of bytes, and reorder the list of global variables so your GlobalVariable is first in the list.

That should work… as far as putting valid data at 0x0 can be said to work…